# ASP Net Core CORS error during put request

Tags: c#, angularjs, ionic-framework, asp.net-web-api, cors

I'm currently developing a ASP Net Core API, and when I try to send a PUT request for the server I get the return error:

***Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource***

I've all ready set the app.EnableCors() and services.EnableCors(), but even after that I get the error message.

Here is the code:

```
public class CorsMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public CorsMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Accept-Encoding, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Date, X-Api-Version, X-File-Name");
        context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,GET,PUT,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS");
        if (context.Request.Method == "OPTIONS")
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
            await context.Response.WriteAsync(string.Empty);
        }

        await _next(context);
    }
}

// Extension method used to add the middleware to the HTTP request pipeline.
public static class CorsMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseCorsMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<CorsMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

And the Startup.cs looks like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddCors();
     services.AddMvc(ConfigureMvcOptions);
     services.AddSwaggerGen(ConfigureSwaggerOptions);
}

 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
 {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwagger();

        app.UseMiddleware(typeof(CorsMiddleware));
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc();
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this exact problem 2 days ago. My solution was to short circuit the pipeline when it's an options request. I don't know what happens in the other middleware but something else is changing the statuscode after you have set it. And really for an options preflight request, you probably don't need anything else to execute anyways.

Change this:

```
    if (context.Request.Method == "OPTIONS")
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
        await context.Response.WriteAsync(string.Empty);
    }

    await _next(context);
```

to this:

```
    if (context.Request.Method == "OPTIONS")
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
        await context.Response.WriteAsync(string.Empty);
    }
    else
    {
        await _next(context);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Lee O. but even after that I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: the service.UseCors() shouldn't be needed. Your custom middleware is not dependent on any registered services. Also, your extension method isn't getting called but you are doing what it does anyways in the app.UseMiddleware(typeof(CorsMiddleware)); You could replace that with app.UseCorsMiddleware();

Comment: If you still get the issue after these changes, I'd try hitting the endpoint through Postman or something without a preflight options request and see if you are still getting a 500.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your `Startup.cs` file

In the `ConfigureServices` method add;

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowLocalhost",
    builder => builder
    .AllowAnyOrigin()
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowCredentials()
    .SetPreflightMaxAge(TimeSpan.FromDays(5)));
});
```

Then in the `Configure` method add;

```
app.UseCors("AllowLocalhost");
```

Comment: Thank you mojoblanco, but after I've added this I get a ***No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. The response had HTTP status code 500.*** error

Comment: Same problem here. That solution doesn't seems to make any difference.  As far as I see, it should work but it does not.